# Copying a cell's background colour to other multiple cells via script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

**Update (01/10/2019); code is now:**

```
function copyFormatting() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var fromRangeGJ14 = sheet.getRange("GJ14");
    var toRangeGJ14 = sheet.getRangeList(['N9','O10','P11']);
    var backgroundsGJ14 = fromRangeGJ14.getBackgrounds();
    toRangeGJ14.setBackground(backgroundsGJ14);
}
```

This works very well, but now I want to create many iterations of it in the same sheet, what would be the best way to do this? As an example, if I were to paste the script twice without any optimisation it would look like this:

```
function copyFormattingGJ14() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var fromRangeGJ14 = sheet.getRange("GJ14");
    var toRangeGJ14 = sheet.getRangeList(['N9','O10','P11']);
    var backgroundsGJ14 = fromRangeGJ14.getBackgrounds();
    toRangeGJ14.setBackground(backgroundsGJ14);
} 
function copyFormattingGJ15() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var fromRangeGJ15 = sheet.getRange("GJ15");
    var toRangeGJ15 = sheet.getRangeList(['N22','O23','P24']);
    var backgroundsGJ15 = fromRangeGJ15.getBackgrounds();
    toRangeGJ15.setBackground(backgroundsGJ15);
}
```

As you can see the second block differs slightly to the first; is there a tidier way of organising the code as I want to essentially run this probably daily, and I don't mind typing it in manually?

**Update (13/09/2019); code is now:**

```
function copyFormatting() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var fromRangeGI14 = sheet.getRange("GI14");
    var toRangeGI14 = sheet.getRangeList(['N9','O10','P11']);
    var backgroundsGI14 = fromRangeGI14.getBackgrounds();
    toRangeGI14.setBackgrounds(backgroundsGI14);
}
```

However I am getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot find function setBackgrounds in object RangeList. (line 6, file "Code"

How do I alter this so that the setbackgrounds function applies the background colour from cell GI14 to cells N9, O10, and P11?

**Original Post:**
Going off this thread here [Cell reference with colour formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50409/cell-reference-with-colour-formatting)

I have modified the script from Vidar to this:

```
function copyValuesAndFormatting() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var fromRangeGI13 = sheet.getRange("GI14");
    var toRangeGI13 = sheet.getRange("N9,N10,N11");
    var backgroundsGI13 = fromRangeGI13.getBackgrounds();
    toRangeGI13.setBackgrounds(backgroundsGI13);
}
```

I understand that line 4 here does not work (I am trying to reference a range, but I have instead put multiple cells instead of a range - this is intentional as I want to target multiple cells that may not be in a row or in order).

The goal here is copying the background's colour from Cell GI13 to Cells N9, N10, and N11; what do I have to do to the existing script here in order to achieve this effect?

My eventual goal is copying backgrounds from around a hundred cells, to thousands of individual cells, and not necessarily ranges, but individual odd cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getRange(A1Notation)` requires that A1Notation be a single A1 notation reference. As the cells are contiguous, try `N9:N11`.

Another option is to use `getRangeList(A1Notations)` where `A1Notations` is an Array of `A1` notation strings, in this case `['N9','N10','N11']` but as `getRangeList` returns a Class RangeList object more changes should be made to the Vidar's code, specifically instead of `setBackgrounds`, if the you want the same background to all the ranges you could use `setBackground(color)` (without the ending `s`).

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setbackgroundcolor

Related

- [How to select multiple, non-consecutive cells in Google Sheets using a list of the cell addresses](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/91103/88163)

Related Q/A from SO

- [setFormulas and rangeList](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53919191/1595451)

Comment: Thanks I'm a lot closer now, the script I am using now looks like this:
function copyValuesAndFormatting() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var fromRangeGI14 = sheet.getRange("GI14");
    var toRangeGI14 = sheet.getRangeList(['N9','N10','N11']);
    var backgroundsGI14 = fromRangeGI14.getBackgrounds();
    toRangeGI14.setBackgrounds(backgroundsGI14);
} <br/>

I'm receiving this error though:

TypeError: Cannot find function setBackgrounds in object RangeList. (line 6, file "Code")

Comment: @JoshuaShenton I'm sorry, the solution is simpler than using getRangeList. Instead of "N9,N10,N11" use "N9:N11"

Comment: Sorry I am aware of putting ranges like this, I should have clarified, that I would like to be able to reference odd cells, for example "N9, O10, P11"

Comment: @JoshuaShenton Please edit the question to add to it the clarification and the code that you tried.

Comment: That's updated now

Comment: @JoshuaShenton I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this works very well now and achieves what I am trying to do. I want to replicate it many times over so I will update the main message momentarily with final steps

Comment: @JoshuaShenton if update will show a solution, post it as an answer. If it will be a follow question post it as a new question, please.